# Change the style of h1, h2, only in post entry

Tags: plugins, customization, options

I would like to change the style of h1, h2, ... ONLY in post entry (when writing a new post).

[image]

Default settings is just too big and has a different format, because I use Google fonts. I was using just bbcode for writing articles and want to start using the headings in articles.

The best solution would be to have the same format as used Google font on the site, but just use bold and different size.

Comment: It's not really clear what's the goal. What's the effect this should have in the front end? And why only in new posts?

Comment: I just want to change the attributes of each heading style. 

For ex.:
Heading 1 - font size 15px; bold type
Heading 2 - font size 12px;
.
.
.

Not only new posts, all post. But it will affect only the new posts because I did NOT use the headings until today.
And dont want to affect the Page titles ;-)

Comment: Well, does @Milo Answer works for you? If not, it's for lack of clarity/details in your Question...

Comment: I believe this is a pure CSS question...

Answer (score 2):

You can change the styling of the editor content with your own CSS stylesheet via the [`add_editor_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) function:

```
function wpa_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_add_editor_styles' );
```

Then in your stylesheet, add your rules:

```
body#tinymce.wp-editor h1 {
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Is there any option to edit just the css file?

I have defined this in css:
http://pastebin.com/Wf2i5YRW

I mean just add few code to the bottom of the css. Something like this:
h1 { font-size: 24px; }

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to change. Those styles look like they are for the *front end*, this is for changing what text looks like in the *back end*- only the editor, not what visitors see.

Comment: Finally, I have found it here:
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight:bold;}
h1{font-size:20px;line-height:30px;}
h2{font-size:18px;line-height:26px;}
h3{font-size:14px;line-height:24px;}
h4{font-size:14px;line-height:20px;}
h5{font-size:14px;line-height:20px;}
h6{font-size:14px;line-height:20px;}
anyway, thanks